# Strange result from file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?php

    $content = file_get_contents('http://www.inc.com/patricia-fletcher/how-to-avoid-the-most-common-start-up-marketing-mistakes.html');
    var_dump($content);

?>
```

Why returns this?

[image: strange result]

If I replace the URL with *http://google.com* everything seems to be fine.

Comment: Because that's what the site returns. (Mostly happens for sites not honoring Accept-Encoding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is returning the content gzip:ed.

[image: Screenshot from inspector]

You therefore need to `gunzip` it to be able to read it. One way would be to use the [Zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zlib.php) functions:

```
$zd = gzopen('http://www.inc.com/patricia-fletcher/how-to-avoid-the-most-common-start-up-marketing-mistakes.html', "r");
$contents = gzread($zd, 100000);
gzclose($zd);

echo $contents;
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>

    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <title>How to Avoid the Most Common Start-Up Marketing Mistakes | Inc.com</title>
<meta name="description" content="Know when and where to invest and get the most from your marketing dollars" />

...
```

Comment: Can I check if is gzip compressed?

Comment: If your goal is to get the contents of a URL regardless of it being compressed or not, you don't have to check it when using  `gzopen()`. From the manual: "gzopen() can be used to read a file which is not in gzip format; in this case gzread() will directly read from the file without decompression.". If you want to check it for any other reason you could to a `curl` or `get_headers` call and check the Content-Encoding header returned.

Answer (score 1):

Response is gzip compressed, use [gzdecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php).

```
$c = file_get_contents( 'http://www.inc.com/patricia-fletcher/how-to-avoid-the-most-common-start-up-marketing-mistakes.html' );
echo gzdecode($c);
```